# HMAC on Mountain lion OSX 10.8.3 EXC_CRASH

Tags: c++, macos, openssl, hmac

Looking for a bit of help using OpenSSL's HMAC function. Currently this function is failing on the HMAC call. ONLY for OSX. Both linux and windows os's are working okay.

```c++
QString tradingDialog::HMAC_SHA512_SIGNER(QString UrlToSign, QString Secret){

    QString retval = "";

    QByteArray byteArray = UrlToSign.toUtf8();
    const char* URL = byteArray.constData();

    QByteArray byteArrayB = Secret.toUtf8();
    const char* Secretkey = byteArrayB.constData();

    const EVP_MD *md = EVP_sha512();
    unsigned char* digest = NULL;

    // Be careful of the length of string with the choosen hash engine. SHA1 produces a 20-byte hash value which rendered as 40 characters.
    // Change the length accordingly with your choosen hash engine
    char mdString[129] = { 0 };

    // Using sha512 hash engine here.
    digest = HMAC(md, Secretkey, strlen( Secretkey), (unsigned char*) URL, strlen( URL), NULL, NULL);

    for(int i = 0; i < 64; i++){
        sprintf(&mdString[i*2], "%02x", (unsigned int)digest[i]);
    }
    retval = mdString;
    return retval;
}
```

Comment: What openssl version do you use? [This example](http://pastebin.com/RGDh4s6f) works for me, tested on OSX 10.10.5. Can you try and see what it does for you?

Comment: Using openssl v1.0.1p on 10.8.3 this test also confirmed to work.

Comment: [This documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html) states that "the `QString` class provides a Unicode character string". You should not use `strlen()` on Unicode strings. Try printing the `strlen()` values and see what happens...

Comment: The URL is returning a proper value which is 66. But the Secret because it has not been entered yet is returning a value of 0. Perhaps this is causing an issue on mac? Not all of the commands in my code require a secret key.

Comment: Oops, I overlooked that you used `.toUtf8()`. The test code seems to work with an empty string (length 0).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't say what the problem is on osx, but it looks like you're not nul terminating `mdString`, so try changing it to

```
char mdString[129] = { 0 };
```

The crashlog you linked to shows that your app is aborting because the stack has been corrupted (I assume this happens on exit).

I would say the final `sprintf` is causing this, as it is adding a nul byte after the end of your `mdString` array. Try the above modification and see if that helps.

This ought to crash on all platforms, but I guess you got "lucky".

Comment: The question states a failure "on the HMAC call", at which point `mdString` is not yet used.

Comment: The title of the question says `EXC_CRASH`.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/4jMRAEch Here is a log of the crash on Mac. Like stated this fails on the openssl HMAC() call. it is called from within the function tradingDialog::HMAC_SHA512_SIGNER(QString, QString)

Comment: Your suggestion here has worked to get the program started. But it doesn't seem to be working the way it should on mac.

Comment: Sounds like the crash is fixed. Maybe ask a new question and include the differences between the 2 outputs